# How to enable auto-completion for quotes after non-whitespace character in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, styled-components

Auto-completion for backticks (or quotes in general) is disabled in vscode if you type the backtick after a character (it works if you type after a whitespace, which is my personal current workaround for this issue).

So in `styled-components` you write a component like this:

```
const MyElement = styled.div`
   ...my css
`
```

As you can see the backtick follows the character "v" and so it doesn't auto paste the closing one. I am currently typing this though and on save it formats the whitespace away.

```
const MyElement = styled.div `
   ...my css
`
```

This is a quite minor issue but as an earlier Atom user I am noticing it quite heavily.

Comment: So https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher/commit/f74657e6afa32ce63239a7b0d06ece7409499ac7 has changed since 2014? Or don't you have the bracket matcher (https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher) installed?